# Learning to trade iOS user friendly crypto wallet safety when stored in and transfer for trading or use to purchase or get cashed

Tags: wallet, cryptography, ios, learning

iPhone users best crypto wallet in bitcoin currency trading and transfer for easy access to use and keep safe deposit and profits as a new and first time trading experience  to the trading crypto currency and forex markets and stock exchange

Comment: I’m trying to get my money back from a brokerage account which I used my debit card to purchase bitcoin for first deposit to open my trading account, and then I was told to buy as much bitcoin as I can and I wanna understand how I can buy bitcoin currency with bitcoin currency and because it’s a brokerage company does that mean I have a wallet already or not? Because they want me to get a wallet so they can return my money back in bitcoin currency and then close my account.  What should I do with this situation please help me

Answer (score 1):

- Choose a wallet program/app from a reputable list such as https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet
- Install that wallet program/app on a secure clean PC or phone (as appropriate)
- Get the wallet to give you a receive address (nowadays wallets issue a different address each time)
- Get your brokerage to transfer money to that address
- Get them to tell you the transaction-ID and check that in a [bitcoin explorer](https://www.google.com/search?q=bitcoin+explorer)

---

> I was told to buy as much bitcoin as I can

That's a bit of a red flag.

> I wanna understand how I can buy bitcoin currency with bitcoin currency

That doesn't make sense. Its like buying dollars with dollars. No one does that. Unless some of those dollars are fake dollars or hot dollars. See [Fungibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fungibility)

You can transfer money from one wallet to another. In your case that might be transferring money from your broker's wallet to your wallet.

It can be confusing because some exchanges/brokers etc label an account a "wallet" when it isn't (a wallet holds a private key that only you know, this isn't the way most exchange/broker accounts work, they hold the keys not you)

> first time trading experience to the trading crypto currency and forex markets and stock exchange

Just remember you are jumping into a pool of very hungry, very experienced, well equipped sharks. Don't "invest" any money you would not be happy to lose.